# Securing endpoints in fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, oauth, fastapi

In my main.py, I have the following code-

```
app = FastAPI(docs_url="",)

app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key=os.getenv('SECRET'))

config = Config('.env')
oauth = OAuth(config)

CONF_URL = 'http://localhost:9090/.well-known/openid-configuration'
oauth.register(
    name='google',
    server_metadata_url=CONF_URL,
    client_id=os.getenv('ID'),
    client_secret=os.getenv('SECRET'),
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid email profile'
    }
)

api_url = None

@app.get('/')
async def homepage(request: Request):
    user = request.session.get('user')
    if user:
        data = json.dumps(user)
        html = (
            f'<pre>{data}</pre>'
            '<a href="/logout">logout</a>'
        )
        return HTMLResponse(html)
    return HTMLResponse('<a href="/login">login</a>')


@app.get('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('auth')
    return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)


@app.get('/auth')
async def auth(request: Request):
    try:
        token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    except OAuthError as error:
        return HTMLResponse(f'<h1>{error.error}</h1>')
    user = await oauth.google.parse_id_token(request, token)
    request.session['user'] = dict(user)
    if api_url:
        return RedirectResponse(url=api_url)
    return RedirectResponse(url='/')


@app.get('/logout')
async def logout(request: Request):
    request.session.pop('user', None)
    request.cookies.clear()
    return RedirectResponse(url='/')


@app.get("/api")
async def get_swagger_ui(request: Request):
    global api_url
    api_url = request.url
    user = request.session.get('user')
    if user:
        return get_swagger_ui_html(
            openapi_url="/openapi.json", title="Webapp",)
    else:
        return RedirectResponse(
            url="/login"
        )

# routes
PROTECTED = [Depends(login)]

app.include_router(get_api.router, dependencies=PROTECTED)
```

In the get_api.py file, I have the following conf -

```
router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/api/higs", tags=["higs"])
def get_higs(db: Session = Depends(get_db),
) 
    try:
        <something>
        return x
    except Exception as err:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=400, detail="Invalid parameter : {}".format(err),
        )
```

There are similar other endpoints in the get_api.py file. I wanted to block access to these endpoints without authentication. So in the app.include_router method, I added dependencies. But its not working. I am able to access the endpoint data. For e.g. localhost:8000/api/higs - displays all the data in text that I would get from calling executing the GET endpoint in swagger UI. How can I fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Just add them to the list of dependencies when including the router

Comment: @Isabi Can you please give an example, I didn't understand what to do.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood what your code was doing since it's incomplete. Anyways, I don't think you can authenticate via google out of the box. I could try some possible workarounds, but I'll have to try first.

Comment: Have you tried setting `PROTECTED = [Depends(oauth)]` ? I don't have experience with the google auth API

Comment: Its not google oauth actually, I named it so, you can name it anything. I tried setting PROTECTED = [Depends(oauth)]. It throws an Assertionerror - 
A parameter-less dependency must have a callable dependency

Comment: But from where does OAuth come from? If you don't use the default OAuth2PasswordBearer it is unlikely to work out of the box

Comment: In my case, I am importing OAuth from authlib.integrations.starlette_client

Comment: Then the variable oauth does not have the property google. Probably there's an error that is being raised

Comment: There's no error as such, just that the endpoints should not display the data without the implemented authentication.